# Control data import from Outlook to CRM2011 - is it possible?

Tags: import, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011

For now, I faced with problem of importing contacts from Outlook to CRM: field "Business Phone 2" is not transferred.  I've created test contact in Outlook, defined "Business phone 2" as 111 22 5555555 and import the one into CRM and - number has not been transferred. Moreover, I set "Business phone 2" in CRM as 222 33 6666666 and this change has not been transferred to Outlook as well. I suppose that this field is not mapped between Outlook contact and CRM contact entities at all.
So, I'm interested in handling this import process with plugin and control the process with my own code. So far, I can fire my plugin on contact Create and Update, but I cannot see the pre data to be imported from Outlook.
I'm sure that some of you have already faced with this issue and knows the solution or possible approach. 
What is the possible approach could be? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2006/07/03/655714.aspx 
This is Fields Mapping. 
So as you can see Business phone 2 is not present in mapping